# search a key inside a block of keys with redis

Tags: redis

This is what I am trying to do; I have a bunch of blocks of numbers (integers) not necessarily contiguous  that have some associated data in the form :

```
<from>-<to> -> <data>
```

. Ie :

```
0-9   -> "some_data_a"
10-15 -> "some_data_b"
20-25 -> "some_data_c"
```

So now I get, let's say, number 22, so I would have to somehow retrieve from redis
"some_data_c". I was thinking about having keys like :

```
blocks:0:9
blocks:10:15
blocks:20:25
```

but I have not found the way to do a key range search like :

```
redis-cli> keys block:[from <= 22]:[22 <= to]
blocks:20:25
```

I need to do this as performant as possible. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the ranges are mutually exclusive, simply keep a sorted set with each member's score being the upper bound of the range. Following the data in your example, that would basically result in:

```
ZADD upper 5 "data:0-5" 15 "data:10-15” 25 "data:20-25"
```

Do the same for the lower bounds:

```
ZADD lower 0 "data:0-5" 10 "data:10-15” 20 " data:20-25"
```

Lastly, you'll want to create keys that correspond to the sets' members - these keys will hold the actual data:

```
SET data:0-5 "some_data_a"
SET data:10-15 "some_data_b"
SET data:20-25 "some_data_c"
```

Now, to get your result, do:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE upper 22 +inf LIMIT 0 1
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE lower -inf 22 LIMIT 0 1
```

(assuming you're looking for 22's data)

If the number you're looking for exists in the range blocks, both Z*RANGE commands should return the same data. Values that aren't in the range would result in one of the Z*RANGEs returning nil. Once you have both non-nil results, GET the key that's named by the set member (i.e. GET data:20-25).

Comment: thanks for your answer. This looks good, but it has a problem. Using the example I provided if you look up 17 that would return "some_data_c" when it actually does not fall into any block, so nil should be returned.

Comment: Very true - fixed my answer to handle that :)

Comment: Another edit: since it is possible that "some_data" will be the same for several range blocks and since sets consist of unique members, I changed the answer so that the sets refer to actual key names that, in turn, hold the data. The only thing I'm still not comfortable with is that the upper & lower sets basically hold the same data in their members so that's a little redundant.

Comment: Lastly, to make this as performant as possible, I'd suggest encapsulating the logic in a Lua script.